# Changing the Ticks in LogLinearPlot for representation pH values

Tags: plotting

I need to change the ticks in the xaxis for representation pH values, but the ticks are not dispersed along the range of xaxis. Another question: why the vertical line defined with Epilog is not visible?

```
Kb1 := Kw/Ka1
Kb2 := Kw/Ka2
oh := Kw/x
f[x_] := Cs Kb2 oh/(Kb2 oh + oh^2 + Kb1 Kb2)
ff[x_] = Simplify[f[x]]
Ka1 = 6.2 10^-8
Ka2 = 4.8 10^-13
Cs = 0.1
myTicks[xmin_, xmax_] := {#, -N[Log[10, #]]} & /@FindDivisions[{xmin, xmax}, 5]
LogLinearPlot[ff[x], {x, 1. 10^-15, 15 10^-10},  AxesLabel -> {"pH", "[HA]"}, Ticks -> {myTicks, Automatic},  PlotRange -> All, Epilog -> 
 Line[{{Log[10, 1.725 10^-10], 0}, {Log[10, 1.725 10^-10], 0.1}}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Version 9**

I made `findD` for that.

```
findD[{x1_, x2_}, n_] := FindDivisions[-Log[10, #] & /@ {x1, x2}, n]
myTicks[xmin_, xmax_] := {10^-#, #} & /@ findD[{xmin, xmax}, 10]
```

Have try this code.

```
Kb1 := Kw/Ka1; Kb2 := Kw/Ka2; oh := Kw/x; f[x_] := Cs Kb2 oh/(Kb2 oh + oh^2 + Kb1 Kb2); ff[x_] = Simplify[f[x]]; Ka1 = 6.2 10^-8; Ka2 = 4.8 10^-13; Cs = 0.1;

LogLinearPlot[ff[x], {x, 1. 10^-15, 15 10^-10},
    AxesLabel -> {"pH", "[HA]"},
    Ticks -> {myTicks, Automatic},
    PlotRange -> All
]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

and `AbsoluteOptions[%, PlotRange]` show that your code
`Epilog-> Line[{{Log[10, 1.725 10^-10], 0}, {Log[10, 1.725 10^-10], 0.1}}`
is out of range, so this is my trick for your `Epilog` line.

```
LogLinearPlot[{ff[x], 1/(x - 1.725 10^-10)}, {x, 1. 10^-15, 15 10^-10},
 AxesLabel -> {"pH", "[HA]"},
    Ticks -> {myTicks, Automatic},
     PlotRange -> {0, 0.1}
]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

**version 10**

`LogLinearPlot` does not work as function of `Ticks` in the version 10, and I think that this might be a bug. ( [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64517/16245) is related )
So use `Ticks -> {myTicks[1. 10^-15, 15 10^-10], Automatic}`

```
LogLinearPlot[{ff[x], 1/(x - 1.725 10^-10)}, {x, 1. 10^-15, 15 10^-10}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"pH", "[HA]"}, 
    Ticks -> {myTicks[1. 10^-15, 15 10^-10], Automatic}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 0.1}
]
```

> [image]

Comment: Very nice. Thanks. Is there a way to increment  the resolution to one decimal place? why the Epilog instruction don't work?

Comment: @Jorge `AbsoluteOptions[%, PlotRange]` is not a sense of your `Epilog` value.

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

In version 10,

```
LogLinearPlot[ff[x], {x, 10^-15, 15 10^-10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    Automatic}, {Table[{10^j, -j}, {j, -15, -9}], None}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"pH", "[HA]"}, 
 GridLines -> {{{1.725 10^-10, Red}}, None}]
```

[image]