# Functional defined Ticks of LogLinearPlot does not work

Tags: plotting, bugs, ticks, logarithmic-scale

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 12.0**

---

**version 10**

```
$Version
```

> "10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)"

Consider three cases in `LogLinearPlot`'s option `Ticks`:

```
findDivisions[{x1_, x2_}, n_] := FindDivisions[-Log[10, #] & /@ {x1, x2}, n]
myTicks[x1_, x2_] := {10^-#, #} & /@ findDivisions[{x1, x2}, 10]

p1 = LogLinearPlot[Log[10, x], {x, 10^-10, 10},
   Ticks -> {myTicks[10^-10, 10], Automatic}];
p2 = LogLinearPlot[Log[10, x], {x, 10^-10, 10},
   Ticks -> {myTicks, Automatic}];
p3 = LogLinearPlot[Log[10, x], {x, 10^-10, 10},
   Ticks -> {Function[{x1, x2}, {10^-#, #} & /@ 
       findDivisions[{x1, x2}, 10]], Automatic}];

Grid[{{"p1", "p2", "p3"}, {p1, p2, p3}}, Frame -> All]
```

> [image]

`p1` is right.

`p2` is wrong with message "Tick specification must be a list or a function".

`p3` is wrong with `FindDivisions`'s error.

[this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64495/16245) is related.

**version 9**

```
$Version
```

> "9.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) (January 24, 2013)"

All three cases well worked!

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: The same behavior in v.10.0.1. It is a bug: clear contradiction to the Documentation.

Comment: Somewhat related: [(54578)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54578/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let us see how `LogPlot` in *Mathematica* 10.0.1 handles the default and custom `Ticks` specifications for the log-axis:

```
Options[LogPlot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}], Ticks]
Options[LogPlot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {Automatic, f}], Ticks]
Options[LogPlot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {Automatic, f@## &}], Ticks]
Options[LogPlot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {Automatic, Range[10]^2}], Ticks]
```

> ```
> {Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}]}}
>
> {Ticks -> {Automatic, Visualization`Utilities`ScalingDump`scaleTicks[{Log, Exp}, f]}}
>
> {Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`FindScaledTicks[(f[##1] &)[##1], {Log, Exp}] &}}
>
> {Ticks -> {Automatic, {{0, 1}, {Log[4], 4}, {Log[9], 9}, {Log[16], 16}, 
>     {Log[25], 25}, {Log[36], 36}, {Log[49], 49}, {Log[64], 64}, {Log[81], 81}, 
>     {Log[100], 100}}}}
> ```

According to the Documentation page for `Ticks`, when the functional form is used it must accept two arguments. This means that `` Visualization`Utilities`ScalingDump`scaleTicks `` must have `SubValues` in order to function properly:

```
SubValues[Visualization`Utilities`ScalingDump`scaleTicks]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

There are no `SubValues` and the functional form returns unevaluated.

When pure function is used, we get evaluatable pure function `` Charting`FindScaledTicks[(f[##1] &)[##1], {Log, Exp}] & ``. Unfortunately, this function is implemented incorrectly - it must pass to `f` the plot range in the natural coordinate system (i.e. from `0.01` to `370`) but instead it passes the actual plot range (i.e. from `Log[0.01]` to `Log[370]`):

```
Reap[Image@LogPlot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {Automatic, Sow[{##}] &}]][[2, 1]]
Exp[%]
```

> ```
> {{-4.55639, 5.91396}}
> {{0.0104999, 370.171}}
> ```

One workaround is to avoid functional `Ticks` inside of the `*Log*Plot` functions and move them in the outer `Show`. It requires another implementation of ticks-generating function as it is already made in the `` CustomTicks` `` package which currently continues development as a part of the [SciDraw package](http://scidraw.nd.edu/):

```
<< CustomTicks`
Show[LogPlot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}], Ticks -> {Automatic, LogTicks}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank a lot for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I agree this is an unfortunate situation. I guess you can pass x value range to plot and your desired division. For illustration only:

```
g[xmin_, xmax_] := 
 Table[{j, 
    Style[Superscript[10, Log10[j]], Red, 12, 
     ScriptSizeMultipliers -> 0.7, 
     ScriptBaselineShifts -> 1.5], {0.03, 0}}, {j, 
    PowerRange[xmin, xmax, 10]}] /. 
  Style[Superscript[x_, a : (0 | 1)], b__] :> 
   Style[Superscript[x^a, ""], b]
yt = Join[{#, #, {0.04, 0}} & /@ Range[-3, 3], {#, #, {0.02, 0}} & /@ 
    Range[-3.5, 3.5, 1]];
```

then

```
LogLinearPlot[Log10[x], {x, ##}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{yt, None}, {g[##], None}}] & @@ {1/10000, 1000}
```

[image]

but agree would be nice if functioned as it does in `Plot`

Comment: Thank you for an fine example about the `Ticks`

Answer (score -3):

In:

```
LogLinearPlot[Log[10, x], {x, 10^-10, 10},Ticks -> {myTicks, Automatic}];
```

myTicks is not evaluated to a list of anything; it's just a symbol. If you evaluate:

```
myTicks[10^-10, 10]
```

you get:

```
{{100, -2}, {1, 0}, {1/100, 2}, {1/10000, 4}, {1/1000000, 6}, {1/
 100000000, 8}, {1/10000000000, 10}}
```

which is a list. Don't know about Version 9, but The error message for p2 with Version 10 means exactly what it says. It seems that the code below supports my  interpretation.

```
myTicks[x1_, x2_] := {10^-#, #} & /@ findDivisions[{x1, x2}, 10] 
Head[myTicks]
Symbol
```

But, this does work:

```
myTicks[min_, max_] := Table[i, {i, Ceiling[min], Floor[max], 1}]
LogPlot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {myTicks, Automatic}]
```

Comment: myTicks is a function. p2 is exactly right syntax.

Comment: I don't think it's evaluated as a function without brackets and arguments. I tested it. But perhaps I made a mistake.

Comment: `myTicks` is just a `Symbol` and it is well-documented way to specify a ticks generating function. The generation of the `Ticks` specification is made `Dynamic`ally by a callback from the FrontEnd to the Kernel.

Comment: So, why doesn't p2 have the proper ticks?

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe It is a bug in the log-plotting code. See [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html#814353806) the documented and expected behavior.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I found a tick function that does work with LogPlot.  Why does this work?

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe It works because in your example the function is applied only to the **linear** axis. The bug appears when you apply it to the log-axis: `LogPlot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {Automatic, myTicks}]`.